# Calculate percentage used from List variables using Ansible playbook

Tags: math, ansible, aggregate

I'm new to ansible environment. I'm working on some coding stuff and got stuck at below.

I got below output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ry2st.png)

I'm looking for the output like below for each aggregate in above list.
aggr_name: ag_xxxxx
aggr_used%: [int] ==> (used/size *100)

I tried with multiple options i got in web but no luck. please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the **code, logs, output, error messages... in the question body as code blocks**. Using images for this has [numerous disadvantages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and is specifically listed as a bad practice in [ask]. Thanks

Comment: Please post the code as text, not an image.

Answer (score 0):

a solution with `%` or not: i am using jinja filters `float` and `round`

```
- name: "tips1"
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    aggr_capacity:
      - aggr_name: ag1
        aggr_space:
          aggr_available: 123456
          aggr_size: 4227703668736
          aggr_used: 616585302016
      - aggr_name: ag2
        aggr_space:
          aggr_available: 123456
          aggr_size: 1585388896256
          aggr_used: 22686273536
      - aggr_name: ag3
        aggr_space:
          aggr_available: 123456
          aggr_size: 1585388896256
          aggr_used: 119851876352
  tasks:  
    - name: solution set_fact
      set_fact:
        result: "{{ result | default([]) + [ { 'aggr_name': name, 'used': used, 'pct': pct ~ '%' } ] }}"
      loop: "{{ aggr_capacity }}"
      vars:
        name: "{{ item.aggr_name }}"
        used: "{{ (item.aggr_space.aggr_used  / item.aggr_space.aggr_size ) | float | round(2)}}"
        pct: "{{ (item.aggr_space.aggr_used  / item.aggr_space.aggr_size  * 100 )| float | round(2)}}"

    - name: debug users      
      debug:
        var: result
```

result:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "result": [
        {
            "aggr_name": "ag1",
            "pct": "14.58%",
            "used": "0.15"
        },
        {
            "aggr_name": "ag2",
            "pct": "1.43%",
            "used": "0.01"
        },
        {
            "aggr_name": "ag3",
            "pct": "7.56%",
            "used": "0.08"
        }
    ]
}
```